# How do I install ogg-opus codecs on my Meizu Pro5

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, ogg-opus

I would like to play ogg-opus music files on my Meizu Pro5.
Not interested in encoding, just playback. I have the terminal app installed, but do not know which files to apt-get install.

The operating system is Ubuntu 15.04  (OTA-11).

Thanks

Comment: PSA: You do not use apt(-get) at all on your phone! — That being said I saw a discussion on the mailing list a few weeks back that an update to the version gstreamer on the phone for decoding Opus is required and in the works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing OTA-13 took care of the og-opus problem. Created others of course, but now i can listen to soothing music while dealing with other Touch frustrations.